# Measure Tomcat's Shutdown Interval

Tags: java, python, tomcat

I am trying to measure my Tomcat server shutdown interval and write it to the log. I'm trying to use the following Python code:

```
    log_times.append(datetime.now().strftime(TIME_PATTERN)) # logs start time
    subprocess.check_call(['service', 'tomcat7', 'stop'])
    pid = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-utomcat7'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    while (pid != ''):
        log.info('pgrep found tomcat process: %s', pid)
        pid = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-utomcat7'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    log_times.append(datetime.now().strftime(TIME_PATTERN)) # logs tomcat shutdown time
```

Is there a better \ accurate way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can  try use a bash script. For example stop_tomcat.sh:

```
START=$(date +%s.%N)
service tomcat7 stop
END=$(date +%s.%N)
DIFF=$(echo "$END - $START" | bc)
echo $DIFF
```

Change permissions :

```
chmod 755
```

call it from python and take it stdout :

```
time = subprocess.Popen(['./stop_tomcat.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

More details about measuring time in bash https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12069.

Comment: thanks for your comment @user2187298, but as far as I can tell, I `service tomcat7 stop` invokes Tomcat's `shutdown.sh` which is asynchronous (the script will end before terminating the process, so this kind of measurement won't be accurate.